# Invisible quotes in the html/twig template files

Tags: html, character-encoding, twig, invisible

I am finding some weird invisible character quotes in firebug when I inspect the html file in the browser. Because of this the layout of html is screwed little bit.

Is this anything to do with the encoding. Because this is happening after i changed the character encoding to utf-8. I tried to change it to previous encoding but the problem still persists.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem? I tried all sorts of things but still not working out.

Comment: Yes encoding has certainly something to do with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using utf-8 with BOM you have to change it to utf-8 without BOM.